# JS cookie sometimes not setting

Tags: javascript, cookies

if front of my head section I'm doing this:

```
<head>
  <script>
    function setCookie(cname, cvalue, exdays) {
      var d = new Date();
      d.setTime(d.getTime() + (exdays*24*60*60*1000));
      var expires = "expires="+ d.toUTCString();
      document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue + ";" + expires + ";path=/";
    }

    setCookie('testCookie', 'testCookieValue', 1);

    function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
        (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
        m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
        })(window,document,'script','https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

    ga('create', 'UA-XXXXXXX-X', 'auto');
    ga('send', 'pageview');
  </script>
  ..
</head>
```

later with django (python framework) Im checking if cookie exists:

```
if 'testCookie' in request.COOKIES:
    testValue = request.COOKIES['testCookie']  
else:
    testValue = 'no Value'
```

And sometimes testValue return "testCookieValue" and sometimes "no Value". What reasons can cause that cookie is not set?

Comment: When setCookie is called? When cookie expires probably jango has no access for it

Comment: `later with jango Im checking if cookie exists` is that on the server, I'm not familiar with what `jango` is

Comment: Im setting cookie for 1 day. And Im checking its value not later than after 1hour.
sorry, made mistake. Should be django.